# What are the best LOD methods for planetary rendering?

Tags: opengl, c++, unreal, level-of-detail, planet

I've been studying how to render planets for a while now. In 2013, a similar question, [Which is the best LOD method for planet rendering?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55731/which-is-the-best-lod-method-for-planet-rendering) was asked. 
 And the answers were:
 1. CDLOD  
2. GPUGCM 
3. Chunked LOD 
4. Geometrical MipMapping 
I've researched each of the discussed methods, and even worked with the authors of [WorldScape](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/worldscape-pro-plugin-make-planet-and-infinite-world) on how they rendered their planet. But now in 2022, I was wondering if there are new methods of which I'm unaware of that might be better than previously discussed methods. I'm running this in Unreal Engine 5. 
Thanks!

Comment: [The same comment that House ♦ left 9 years ago](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55731/which-is-the-best-lod-method-for-planet-rendering#comment96682_55731) is still true: 'There is no universally "best" method. Only you know all the requirements of your project and you appear to know about a number of LOD options.' - a decade hasn't fundamentally altered the nature of game development: we usually don't have a documented/agreed-upon best practice to go from, and there's a lot of individual experimentation and evaluation to find the methods that are right for each game's needs.

Comment: UE5 has a new geometry LODing method as a built-in feature.